# The waste hose on washing machine sits on floor/low

Tags: washing-machine

We have a smell that I'm sure comes through from the standpipe when washing machine is in use. The standpipe doesn't seem to smell after use though(like this evening, last wash was earlier in day). The waste hose is loose on floor and then loosely hung into the standpipe about 6" . The hose is not clipped to the back of the machine (which would make the pipe vertical, then horizontal to the standpipe , would this cause some form of backflow having it loose? The reason I haven't used the mounting clip on back of machine as it then stops the machine being pulled forward and looks to put pressure on the hose going into the standpipe.
Hose is bottom right of rear (if standing in front of door) and clip vertically above it. Standpipe is on left side wall . If I removed the bend thing then it may be mountable.

Comment: Not sure I followed you, are you asking if a loose fitting could create back flow? There is normally an air gap where the hose enters the stand pipe and no back flow would be possible.

Comment: Yeah I was asking if having the grey flexible hose from the washing machine just hanging on floor and then dangled in the standpipe so the flex hose is drooping.   It looks like the manufacturer wants the hose clipped vertically straight up the back of the machine and then horizontal just beneath the top/lid and in to the standpipe..would the droop cause stagnant water? Could the smell be from inside the machine? How do I pinpoint where it's coming fromm

Comment: If possible, add a picture of your standpipe setup to your question.  Ideally, it will have a trap at the bottom, and be connected to a vent just downstream of that trap.  If you don't have this (older homes often won't) try pouring a liter of water down the standpipe each day for a week or two.  If that prevents a return of the smell, the odor is coming from the drain itself, not from the machine or its hose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there will be a little stagnant water but there always is the pump is in the bottom of the machine and it can only push water out as long as there is water to push when the pump stops the pipe is still full any extra pipe on the ground will add to that amount but a couple of inches won’t be more than a cup or 2 added to what is there no washer that I know of empty’s that last quart or so of water.